# which IDEs are available for Freertos with Stm32 IDE for Linux?

Tags: arduino, avr, stm32, linux, freertos

Is there any IDE available for Freertos or Stm32 for specifically only for Linux other than Keil uvision. because I found out that Keil uvision is the most stable IDEs available out there for embedded systems.

There is 1 or 2 IDE available for Linux for Embedded System Like for beginners its Arduino. and for advance eclipse. but I want something like Atmel studio . and one more thing eclipse is very unstable when it comes to the embedded system there are lots of configuration and I can't find the best method to setup eclipse for each and every controller. So like Keil has Atmel and stm32 both support. we can easily compile and upload a code for ATMEL chips using Atmel studio so for Linux, Which IDEs are available for Chips? I know command line tools like avr-gcc and arm-gcc but i want something like ready to code. thank you.

Comment: "most embedded engineers use Linux" ... says who? And were they referring to the platform they were developing *on* or the platform they were developing *for*?

Comment: IIRC IDE stands for Integrated Drive Electronics, so what are you looking for?

Comment: @brhans actually Linux (and Macs) are very popular for development of all sorts, including embedded.  That's doubly so when an embedded gadget needs to be part of a larger software ecosystem - being able to utilize the same automated build and test tools as the rest of the company matters.  But conversely, those solutions are not IDE-based, therefore production *building* is distinct from what your type into and interface a debugger via, the latter even potentially being a choice made differently by every individual on a project, without issue... This questions is too broad to really fit here.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_do_most_of_the_embedded_system_developers_use_Ubuntu_Linux_distribution @brhans

Comment: @SolarMike IDEs means integrated development enviroment in softwares

Comment: You should explain any terms that are ambiguous...

Comment: oh thanks @ChrisStratton can you provide any help please this will help to those beginers also who are trying to achive something with linux and embedded systems

Comment: Simple: separate editing, from looking up information, from building, from source control.  Do that and you'll be able to sit at any computer running a sane operating system, use any developer-friendly company's chip, and move your results readily between experiment and production.

Comment: ya i mean that arduino is available for all Linux , Mac, and Windows. but when it comes to port manipulation for arduino its easy to go with AVR studio. so what for Linux ? you use avrdude. but when it comes to arm there is only one option and its arm-gcc with eclipse or makefile but no easy IDE is available . then why linux ?

Comment: @ChrisStratton but what i am saying is  i want name of tools for arm. like arm-gcc but i want some gui tool later on its easy to build makefile but first at start can i have some tools to start atleast building ? except for eclipse. eclipse is litteraly very buggy

Comment: Stop looking for an IDE.  The ASF software library that backs Atmel studio is available as a host-agnostic download archive.  And Atmel studio uses (ready for this?) gcc to compile for most of its targets.  The part that's not portable is the horrid visual-studio based interactive environment.

Comment: @ChrisStratton why don't you share us some links ? it will be more helpfull

Comment: can i get help in terms of stm32 ? @ChrisStratton which IDEs or tools i choose to compile because i see so many code on github but unable to compile i can just read or understand the logic for stm32 and i dont want to use stm32duino . i want to use stm32 alone using arm-gcc

Comment: IDE's do not compile.  Compilers compile.  Most github projects have a build system or intended environment of some sort.

Comment: I've used Eclipse on Linux to develop bare-metal ARM code and it works fine for me. Not at all unstable.

Comment: STM32 and AVR are two separate architectures. Pick one.

Comment: @SolarMike it’s not ambiguous in this question.

Comment: For STM32 jut use the official IDE from ST - Atollic TrueSTUDIO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, just find a good makefile and use a good text editor - sublime, vim, emacs, kate, atom, vscode,... With a good makefile, all you need to do is keep the source file list up to date and then run "make" and "make program".  Then you can use this same setup for all of your programming, no matter the target.

Comment: Yes, that's what i am learning right now because i know one thing `makefile` is the sword with too many functions you can do anything with makefile but before that for just quickstart purpose i want one ide . bdw thank you for reminding me that i am not alone in love with makefile